# Facebook app works only with admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a facebook app for my site and an html page where i can login into the user  account allowing the app for do that...

So, this work correctly when i attempt to logon with the my account, that are the ADMIN of the page, but with other else account, the facebook popup window retrieve an error (with no useful details).. my sensation is that the app is not open to the public, how i can open it for the public?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you haven't forgotten to take the app out of Sandbox mode in the app's advanced settings?

Answer (score 0):

By default sandbox mode is not enabled, but yes try this way. If it's not that can you please bring us some code?

Comment: At moment i've disabled it and works with my sister's account (she's not an admin)... but for the final confirm i've to wait the response if my friend!

What kind of code you want? I've used a mix of javascript and actionscript, considering that my site is realized full in flash